Python geodataframe issue with function explore()
I have a GeoDataFrame data as below:

I want to explore this data with function explore(), however this does not work (the map is not showing anything):
gdf.explore(column='value3', cmap='OrRd', legend=True)

At the same time limiting data to 50k records works fine and data is visible on the map:
gdf[:50000].explore(column='value3', cmap='OrRd', legend=True)

The same with plotting by function plot - data is visible:
gdf.plot(column='value3', cmap='OrRd', legend=True)

Another interesting fact is that when I merge all Point objects with value3=0 into one single MultiPoint object then the data is visible again.
What is wrong with the first line of code?
Is it some issue with data size?
